# Android navigation drawer inner shadow

Tags: java, android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I have followed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) example to create a side sliding navigation menu inside my app. Now I need to add a inner shadow on the right side of the menu. I've been looking for an example on the internet but no success. Can anyone tell me is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is and there is actually a method for it:

1-save a drawable of the desired shadow.

2-`navigationDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.dShadow, GravityCompat.START);`

**GravityCompat.START** shadow position.

[Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerShadow(int,%20int))

If you need more customization on your drawer you can check out these links:

[Custom 1](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/)

[Custom 2](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Answer (score 1):

```
 mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
```